# WSL: Is there a conditional to detect "Open Linux Shell Here" case?

Tags: bashrc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I open the WSL by clicking on its icon I need it to be opened in a certain directory (of course one that is more useful than `System32`), so I add a `cd destination` in my `.bashrc`. But then the "Open Linux Shell Here" option (available when you hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key on keyboard and right-click on any folder is also being redirected to that destination, which is undesirable. Is there a way I can detect this case in my `.bashrc` script and let it behave as it should?

In short, I need to know when the shell has been opened by the option in <kbd>Shift</kbd>+*Right Click* inside a folder, so that I can avoid changing the working directory to another one.

I'm using `WSL-Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` and `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the `~/.bashrc` enhancement to something like this:

```bash
CurrDir="$(pwd)"
if [[ "$CurrDir" == "$SystemDir" ]]
then
    cd /path/to/sensible-dir-name
Fi
```

Where `$SystemDir` is your System32 directory. Always remember how `\` and `/` differ between Windows and Linux paths:

- [Bash script to convert Windows path to Linux path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999562/bash-script-to-convert-windows-path-to-linux-path)

Suggests using:

```bash
sed -e 's#^J:##' -e 's#\\#/#g'
```

That said in your instance you could probably hard-code the path.

Comment: You can use wslpath for the conversion: `if [[ "$CurrDir" == $(wslpath -u "$SystemDir") ]]

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez `$SystemDir` is an empty variable for me

Comment: @winklerrr `SystemDir` needs to be populated with your Windows System Directory name before you can test against it.

Answer (score 1):

## VSCode and TMUX compatible

You can add the following code to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
alias current_dir="pwd | sed -e 's/ /\\ /'"
alias save='echo $(current_dir) > ~/.saved_dir && echo "saved current dir, use \"load\" to cd to it"'
alias load='builtin cd $(cat ~/.saved_dir 2>/dev/null)'

if [ -n "$PS1" ] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ screen ]] \
  && [[ ! "$TERM_PROGRAM" =~ vscode ]] \
  && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ tmux ]] && [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
  # only load while in interactive console but not in vscode or not in tmux itself

  CURRENT_DIR=$(pwd)
  if [[ "${CURRENT_DIR,,}" == "/mnt/c/windows/system32" ]]; then
    # only load path if we start in default WSL system32 folder 
    # so "open in linux shell" still works
    load
  fi

  if command -v tmux &> /dev/null; then 
    # only run tmux if it is installed
    exec tmux
  fi
fi
```

The code checks if the terminal is run interactively and not inside a VSCode or TMUX session. If that's the case:

- it loads a saved directory (see `save`/`load`) or your home directory if the start path is equal to the `windows/system32` directory (`${CURRENT_DIR,,}` converts the string to lowercase for better matching)
- it automatically starts TMUX if installed (just remove that if you don't like TMUX)

If you then want to change your start directory, just navigate to the directory you want to use as start directory and type `save`. Next time you start your terminal, that directory is loaded automatically.

Check out my dotfiles repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/winklerrr/awesome) for more.